# Как отсортировать элементы массива по значению ключа?

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, angularjs

Ребята нид хэлп!

Есть массив

```
$scope.contacts = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "first name",
        "surname": "first surname",
        "age": "29",
        "group": "group 1",
        "description": "This is first",
        "note": "some notification"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "second name",
        "surname": "second surname",
        "age": "27",
        "group": "group 2",
        "description": "This is first",
        "note": "some notification"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "third name",
        "surname": "third surname",
        "age": "25",
        "group": "group 1",
        "description": "This is first user",
        "note": "some notification"
      }]
```

Дело делается на Angular. В одной вкладке нужно вывести список всех пользователей(с этим проблем нету). Во второй - название групп и ее участников. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отфильтровать по группам!

Список групп, которые существуют получаю так:

```
$scope.selectGroups = new Set();
        $scope.groups = [];
         var test = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.contacts.length; i++) {
                $scope.selectGroups.add($scope.contacts[i].group);
            }

    test = JSON.stringify(Array.from($scope.selectGroups));

    $scope.groups = JSON.parse(test);
```

Начинающий и понимаю, что многого не знаю. Надеюсь на помощь!

Comment: Для чего вы делаете JSON.stringify и сразу JSON.parse ?

Comment: Вам нужно отсортировать по значению ключа (задача в заголовке) или отфильтровать по групппе (описание задачи в тексте)?

Comment: Пробовал выводить на страницу полученный список групп из test, Angular не хотел выводить.После операций с JSON - заработало.

Comment: На страницу нужно выводить название группы и ее участников. Группы могут добавляться. Я так понимаю мне нужен массив с ключами "названия групп" , отобрать список пользователей по группе и получить массив контактов для каждого ключа. Возможно лезу в дебри((

Comment: stringify и parse не нужен, достаточно Array.from.

Comment: массив названий групп у вас уже есть в  $scope.groups, а чтобы получить контакты по группе можно просто для каждой группы выполнить фильтр по `$scope.contacts` по названию группы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отфильтровать можно функцией [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
$scope.contacts.filter( contact => contact.group === 'group 1' ) //оставит кантакты только из группы 1
```

Отсортировать можно функцией [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
$scope.contacts.sort( (contact1, contact2) => contact.group.localeCompare( contact2.group ) ) //отсортирует контакты по группе.
```

Comment: там точно не запятая? ..contact => contact.group..

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin там функция, можете проверить в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

Немного переделал и заработало!

```
    $scope.groups = {};
    $scope.selectGroups = new Map();

             for (var i = 0; i < $scope.contacts.length; i++) {


                 if (!$scope.selectGroups.has($scope.contacts[i].group)) {
                     var users = [];
                     $scope.selectGroups.set($scope.contacts[i].group, users);

                        $scope.selectGroups.get($scope.contacts[i].group).push($scope.contacts[i].name);
                    } else {
                        $scope.selectGroups.get($scope.contacts[i].group).push($scope.contacts[i].name);
                    }

                }

$scope.groups = Array.from($scope.selectGroups);
```

На странице вывожу так:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">

            {{group[0]}}<br>
            <div ng-repeat="gr in group[1]">
                {{gr}}
            </div>

        </div>
```

В результате получаю название групп и ее участников под названием.

Спасибо!